# Resolving service based on model in AppServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, inversion-of-control, service-provider

To give you a brief view: I am trying to make redirect based on conditions. If request satisfy conditions of given destination you will get redirect to certain destination.

I have `Destination` model which has many conditions (Condition model). I have many Conditions which extends basic Condition model like `DateCondition`, `LocationCondition` etc (made by polimorphic relation). Each of condition type should has 'service' which tells if given condition match do the request. Example `DateCondition` should has own `DateConditionMatcher` which implements `ConditionMatcherInterface`.
(just `public function  match($condition, $request)`).

I would like to write it with Open Closed principle from SOLID. Firstly I thought to add `getMatcher()` function straight to condition model and return different `ConditionMatcher` for each condition type, but some of ConditionMatchers need some other services passed in contructor, so it would force me to inject them also in `Condition` models which is bad pratice.

Maybe using Contextual binding in ServiceProvider could resolve this but how?
I have no idea how to couple Model to to the right one ConditionMatcher to then use it freely like this:

```
foreach ($destination->conditions as $condition){
       $isMatched = $this->conditionMatcher->match($condition, $request);
}
```

To always have correct ConditionMatcher under $this->conditionMatcher.
I hope someone understood my not very clear message.

Comment: how are you getting the correct condition matcher for the condition currently?

Comment: do you need new instances of these matchers everytime or can a single instance be used for multiple conditions?  (thinking maybe like a manager class)

Comment: No, I don't need new instances of these matchers, so each matcher should be a singleton. 
I've post the soultion I've done, but if you know better solution please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an idea overnight to make service which keeps all the matchers. The only downside to this solution is injecting every matcher.

```
class ConditionResolver implements ConditionResolverInterface
{
    /** @var ConditionMatcherInterface[] */
    private $conditionMatchers = [];

    public function __construct(
       DateConditionMatcher $dateConditionMatcher, 
       TimeConditionMatcher $timeConditionMatcher,
       LocationConditionMatcher $locationConditionMatcher
    ) {
       $this->conditionMatchers[DateCondition::class] = $dateConditionMatcher;
       $this->conditionMatchers[TimeCondition::class] = $timeConditionMatcher;
       $this->conditionMatchers[LocationCondition::class] = $locationConditionMatcher;
    }
}
```

so now I am able to use correct matcher to given condition in this way(simplified):

```
foreach ($model->conditions as $condition)
{
    $this->conditionMatchers[get_class($condition)]->match($condition, $request);
}
```

It allows me to inject various of services into that matchers in AppServiceProvider.

```
$this->app->singleton(LocationServiceInterface::class, function($app){
   return new LocationService();
});

$this->app->singleton(DateConditionMatcher::class, function($app){
   return new DateConditionMatcher();
});

$this->app->singleton(TimeConditionMatcher::class, function($app){
   return new TimeConditionMatcher();
});

$this->app->singleton(LocationConditionMatcher::class, function($app){
    return new LocationConditionMatcher($app->make(LocationServiceInterface::class));
});
```

Overall I think I miessed something and it would be done in more elegant way, but for now I treat it as an answer. If you have better solution, please share :)